# find everything besides directories

Tags: bash

How can I use `find` command to find every type of the file (not just `-type f` but also specials such as sockets, device files etc.) but ommiting dirs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use negation.

```
find . ! -type d -print
```

Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

Answer (score -1):

You can have o look at *find* manual, but I doubt it is the proper way to find sockets and/or device files... I think the program to find such a device is a different one, don't remember what exactly right now, sorry!

Comment: I'm familiar with find's manual page. There is a way to get e.g. only sockets (e.g. myusql.sock) or only regular files, but not all at once.